# 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver' error occurs when Java application is uploaded as an Azure Web App

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, mssql-jdbc

I've worked on this for a few days whenever I have time and I'm still stumped on why the error occurs.

In the IDE everything works beautifully and I'm able to get a response from the SQL server hosted on Azure. However, once I upload the code to to an Azure Web App I get the following error:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver ......

**The connection string**

```
String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:1433;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;" + "encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;", hostName, dbName, user, password);
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar
Built-By: Author
Created-By: IntelliJ IDEA
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
```

**Snippet of pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

[Location of the jar file when it's uploaded to Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkzZO.png)

There has to be something I'm missing or unaware of.

Comment: Somewhere in your local environment you are probably doing a `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.Driver")` to register it. Are you sure that's the same for production? Or maybe your local application server automatically deploys the driver?

Comment: Actually I wasn't using that line in my code. I had created an different application and uploaded it as an Azure web job without that line in the code and it ran with no issues at all. Likewise, despite the line being missing in the code in my local development environment it ran just fine. Furthermore, I was under the impression that the newer versions of the JDBC driver registered themselves so I didn't think it was necessary. I added the line you suggested for my web application and it worked. Is there a particular reason why the line must be added specifically for web apps on Azure?

Comment: I have zero experience with Azure, so I can't explain why it works. I know Wildfly as an application server for example scans through the module jars, finds a /META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file that contains the driver and automatically registers this. I don't know if Azure has a similar function.